# Return all rows where value appears at least once per group

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table listing groups of individuals and contacts assigned to them. The individual can only belong to one group however they can have multiple contacts and vice versa. An example would appear as follows:

```
+-------+------------+---------+
| Group | Individual | Contact |
+-------+------------+---------+
| A     | J          | X       |
| A     | K          | Y       |
| A     | K          | Z       |
| B     | L          | X       |
| B     | M          | Y       |
| C     | N          | Y       |
| C     | N          | Z       |
| C     | O          | Z       |
| C     | P          | Z       |
+-------+------------+---------+
```

I am working on a way to pull a report for contacts listing all individuals in a group where they appear against at least one of those individuals. So for the above the output would appear as follows (sorted per contact):

```
+-------+------------+---------+
| Group | Individual | Contact |
+-------+------------+---------+
| A     | J          | X       |
| A     | K          | X       |
| B     | L          | X       |
| B     | M          | X       |
| A     | J          | Y       |
| A     | K          | Y       |
| B     | L          | Y       |
| B     | M          | Y       |
| C     | N          | Y       |
| C     | O          | Y       |
| C     | P          | Y       |
| A     | J          | Z       |
| A     | K          | Z       |
| C     | N          | Z       |
| C     | O          | Z       |
| C     | P          | Z       |
+-------+------------+---------+
```

Here we can see that contact X was assigned to individual J (group A) and individual L (group B). Group A has 2 individuals (J and K) and Group B has 2 (L and M) so contact X will see individuals J, K, L and M on their report (everyone in groups A and B).

I'm thinking this will require a derived table grouping by `Group` and then `Contact` but i just can't get my head around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst playing around with a few things i think i may have solved this. The key link here is the group, so by creating some derived tables based on groups of contacts and groups of individuals then linking the two i got the following which gives the desired result:

`select y.con, y.grp, x.ind from
(select grp, ind from tmp group by grp, ind) as x
join 
(select con, grp from tmp group by con, grp) as y on y.grp = x.grp
order by y.con, y.grp, x.ind`

Not sure if this is the best way to do it but it works.